# Posting a tweet as a logged in user in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, twitter

So my problem is that I need to make a tweet (update) using a users authorised session which I retrieved in Flutter using the flutter_twitter_login package. I also have integrated Firebase Authentication and have access to a UserCredential. I also use the dart_twitter_api library for sending Twitter requests. I am new to the Twitter API and Flutter so I would appreciate the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution given my setup and here I will post the details for anyone else in need.

**Firebase authentication is not required** to solve this problem but **you do need the flutter_twitter_login and dart_twitter_api packages**. You can find alternative packages for the latter as well, but not the former as of this time.

You need to pass the Twitter session's token and secret you retrieve after a successful login as the initialisation parameters of the dart twitter API for the values access token and secret respectively.

```
  final twitterApi = TwitterApi(
client: TwitterClient(
  consumerKey: apiKey,
  consumerSecret: apiSecret,
  token: session.token,
  secret: session.secret,
),);
```

From the code above just store the all 4 keys in String variables elsewhere in your Dart library and replace the above references with your variables.